# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada vez que se ingrese un número en un campo de texto, esos ingresos se vayan acumulando en una variable utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, botón, click

¡Hola! Sigo en el proceso de aprender JavaScript utilizando la librería jQuery. Solamente quería saber, ¿cómo puedo hacer que **cada vez** que el usuario ingrese un valor en un campo de texto, esos ingresos se puedan acumular en una variable en mi código?

Les puedo mostrar lo básico de lo que pude ir haciendo, por ejemplo declarar dos variables, pero no sé si está bien el razonamiento hasta ahora:

```
$("#btnAcumular").click(acumular);

let variable1;
let acumulado;

function acumular(){
    variable1 = Number($("#txtAcumular").val());

    alert(variable1);

    acumulado = variable1;
}
```

Comment: Que se vayan sumando. Quiero que cada vez que se ingrese un número en el campo, se acumule el total de esos ingresos en una sola variable para poder después, mostrar el resultado final acumulado.

Comment: Sería preferible sí, ya que intento aprender jQuery, pero si el razonamiento es similar entonces quizás pueda representarlo en mi código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con pequeñas modificaciones sobre tu código lo tienes, basta con inicializar la variable acumulado a 0 y en el `onclick` sumarle el valor de variable1 a acumulado.

```js
$("#btnAcumular").click(acumular);

let variable1;
let acumulado = 0;

function acumular(){
    variable1 = Number($("#txtAcumular").val());

    //alert(variable1);

    acumulado = acumulado+variable1;
    console.log(acumulado);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="txtAcumular">
<input type="button" id="btnAcumular" value="Sumar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría así: 
`variable1+=Number($("#txtAcumular").val())` 
y eliminaría la otra variable. Así estoy concatenando el valor que ya tenía con el nuevo.